# Past simple or past continuous? :/

Tags: past-tense

Robin Hood was a character who ________ from the rich and ____ to the poor. 
a. stole/ gave
b. was stealing/ was giving
What is the write answer and why?

Comment: The usual formulation is *robbed* / *gave*.

Comment: @Robusto: I don't much like ***robbed from*** - to my ear the preposition is actually "awkward", rather than just "unnecessary". See [this NGram...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stole+from+the+rich+and%2Ctook+from+the+rich+and%2Crobbed+from+the+rich+and%2C%2Crobbed+the+rich+and&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstole%20from%20the%20rich%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20from%20the%20rich%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crobbed%20from%20the%20rich%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crobbed%20the%20rich%20and%3B%2Cc0),

Comment: ...which shows that until fairly recently the front-runner was ***robbed the rich***, but in recent decades that's been overtaken by ***stole from the rich***, which has the advantage of "paralleling" the (non-optional) preposition in the contrastive clause *...and gave **to** the poor*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm old-school. I always heard it as *robbed from the rich*. Somehow it seems right that Robin was robbin' ...

Comment: @Robusto: *Before* I go googling to see if I can find anything about it, I just want to say that the little voice in my head is telling me that 50 years ago when I watched a weekly Robin Hood "soap opera" on TV, the song in the introduction was *He **steals** from the rich, and **gives** to the poor*. But I should also admit that I'm getting to the point where I don't necessarily trust my own recollections, having been proved spectacularly wrong on many occasions since having the benefit of Google to check more easily.

Comment: Update: Apparently Google reckons there are 21K instances of present tense ***steals/gives***, but only 7K for past tense ***stole/gave***. But I'm still unsure whether I'm remembering the song from the late 50s / early 60s soap opera, or the much later [Monty Python "Dennis Moore" skit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbtVaTWs6II) (alluding to Dick Turpin rather than Robin Hood).

Comment: @Fumble: Apparently **[takes from the rich](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=takes+from+the+rich%2Csteals+from+the+rich%2Crobs+from+the+rich&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctakes%20from%20the%20rich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csteals%20from%20the%20rich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crobs%20from%20the%20rich%3B%2Cc0)** beats them both. Not sure what that proves.

Comment: @Robusto: Dunno about "proves". But I do think taken in the round the figures strongly suggest that parallel structure is preferred - and since there's no obvious alternative to ***give*** that doesn't require a preposition, we favour a syntactically similar choice for the *first* verb. Compare *Rob Peter to pay Paul*, which works nicely because *neither* verb needs a preposition. Anyway, all this started because I'm not keen on *to rob **from***, and although I can't say that construction is actually "wrong", I still maintain I'm far from alone in tending to avoid it.

Comment: @Fumble: Dunno about "wrong" ... that's part of the beauty of English, that we can say so many different things in so many different ways. Sometimes you want something to sound "awkward" in order to make it stand out ...

Comment: Couldn't agree more! But sometimes that's a bit of a stumbling block here on ELL, 'cos competent/confident native speakers often *deliberately* choose to use "unusual" forms to add subtle implications, but it's not always either practical or *useful* for learners to get bogged down in such details. They risk getting sucked into suboptimal "little knowledge is a dangerous thing" traps, where all they really needed to know is "KISS".

Comment: (incidentally, I'm not really trying to prolong this comment thread, but I'd be very interested to know if the SO "inbox" logic is smart enough to ping you for the above comment, on the grounds that you're the only other user with a preceding post that I might be referring to.)

Answer (score 2):

Robin Hood **"stole"** from the rich and **"gave"** to the poor.  When talking about regularly occurring activities, use the present tense.  For example:

> I *watch* TV every Tuesday afternoon.
>
> She *plays* the violin whenever she gets bored.
>
> The President *formulates* the yearly budget, which the Congress then *ratifies*.

For events that occurred regularly in the past, just use the past simple.

> I watched TV every Tuesday when I was younger.
>
> Before she became a professional musician, she played the violin whenever she got bored.
>
> In the past, the President formulated the budget, which the Congress then ratified.  Nowadays, the process is much more complicated and interconnected.

Answer (score 0):

One of the uses of the simple past is when something happened again and again in the past but one is interested in the action itself.

> ex: I went to school when I was little.
>           This means I went many times or once but the emphasis is on the action.

Past continuous is usually used to highlight the duration of the action and outside of the classroom it almost always comes in contrast with the simple past.

> ex: She was swimming when it began to rain.
>
> So her swimming is shown as an action that took a duration from before
>            the rain and probably until after the rain. the swimming is thus highlithed.

In your example the intuitive answer is A

> Robin Hood was a character who **_stole_____ from the rich and __gave** to the poor.
>
> Because the emphasis is on the action and the moral lesson 
>          rather than how many hours it took him to steal and give.

for more info you see the examples in these pages:
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense/past-simple
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense/past-continuous

Do not forget to tick the answer that you find useful.

Answer (score -2):

I guess it should be past simple! Because it was happening from day to day and was a regular thing. It was his sort of hobby.

Comment: Thnx for answer,.but it is still little bit unclear for me :/